# Unit test for a Web API method without any injected dependency

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I have a method in my Web API project and since it's pretty simple and there is no injected dependency and it deals with a concrete POSTed object, I'm not sure how I could create a unit test for it. Is there anything in the design of the below code I could change to make it more test-friendly?

```
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(RootObject root)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponse;

        return TryCreateResponse(root, out httpResponse) ? httpResponse : Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "An unhandled exception occurred on the server.");
    }

    private bool TryCreateResponse(RootObject root, out HttpResponseMessage httpResponse)
    {
        var success = false;
        httpResponse = null;
        try
        {
            var creator = (ModelState.IsValid)? 
                new OkResponseCreator(root) as IHttpResponseCreator: 
                new BadReqeuestResponseCreator(ApplicationSettings.HttpBadRequestErrorMessage);

            var abstractHttpResponse = new ResponseContext(creator).CreateHttpResponse();
            httpResponse = Request.CreateResponse(abstractHttpResponse.StatusCode, abstractHttpResponse);

            success = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            success = false;
        }

        return success;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd be trying to test TryCreateResponse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by testing `HomeController.Post` with a fake `RootObject` and asserting your expected result with what was actually returned from the test.

Although there are no **injected dependencies**, the method and by extension the class is dependent on `OkResponseCreator`, `BadReqeuestResponseCreator` `ResponseContext` and `ApplicationSettings`.

Given that the extent of the coupling of those classes are not completely obvious in your example and also what are their dependencies, I would suggest you start by looking at those classes.

If your initial test fails, you can try a cycle of refactoring and retesting as you make the mentioned classes mockable so that they can be safely injected into the controller for better testability.